# scala queue sort method

Tags: scala, queue, scala-collections, dijkstra

I am comparing a number of different methods for organizing the nodes at the "frontier"  in dijkstra's single source shortest path algorithm.  One of the implementations that I am playing around with is using q: scala.collection.mutable.Queue.

Essentially, each time I add a node to q, I sort q.  This method, as expected, takes significantly longer than using scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue and a MinHeap that I implemented.  **My question is, what kind of sort is Queue using when I call q.sorted?** I am specifically interested in the time complexity of the sorted implementation.

I have tried looking at the API (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Queue) and code (https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/Queue.scala#L1) but haven't been able to track this down.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If you use Intellij or Eclipse, it's sometimes useful to type the code somewhere: a.sort , then right click "sort" and choose "Go to Implementation".. and you can sometimes get Scala's source code to come up. Then repeat, much easier than browsing online and trying to figure out which trait the code inherits from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Queue` inherits `sorted` method from [SeqLike](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/SeqLike.scala#L607). And you can see, that it creates new array of same elements, sorts array via `java.util.Arrays.sort` and then creates new structure of original type.

Comment: It looks like java.util.Arrays.sort uses merge sort, is this correct?

Comment: It depends on version of JDK and jvm options. In lastest JDK it usually uses Tim sort.